# Make [postal] a synonym of [correspondence-chess]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I'd like to propose that the new [postal](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postal) tag be marked as a synonym of [correspondence-chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correspondence-chess)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that makes sense. I've just created the requested synonym. A friendly reminder to all: please do not create new tags if an existing one sufficiently describes the topic.